# Hiding the middle cell in the tableview animated

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

There are 3 cells in a tableview. I need to hide and display the middle cell animated. The third cell will move up to the place of the middle cell, when the middle cell is hidden. And when the middle cell is displayed again, the third cell will move to its original place. Is there any method to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

and

```
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

but your `dataSource` will also need to reflect that changes at the time these calls are made

```
// delete

NSArray *deleteIndexes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];

UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
// Any other actions for updating the tableView
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: "Note the behavior of this method when it is called in an animation block defined by the beginUpdates and endUpdates methods." what should i do for this sentence in the document of theses two methods?

Comment: If you are doing multiple actions e.g. inserts/deletes or reloads in one go you need to do them in a block. I've amended the code above to just always use a the block

Comment: when i delete the cell i got this error: 2012-04-07 19:11:14.852 myApp[13230:207] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UITableView.m:1046

Comment: You need to make sure that if you delete one row your dataSource reflects this change as well